# Disable scrolling in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, xcode4.2

In my iPad app, I am playing some PDF and Videos on UIWebView. I need to scroll pdf to read further pages. But at the same time the videos are also scrollable, which I want to disable. I am playing all these files on a single web view. I can write a condition to disable scrolling on a video and enable on a PDF. But I have no idea what to write inside the condition. Can anyone help me disabling scrolling of UIWebView.

Thanks

PC

Comment: Could you upload a picture that shows your screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Please note that this technic disables touches and interaction on the web view

Comment: This is not good answer cause you disable everything else, touches included

Answer (score 6):

You can disable scrolling of an entire UIWebView by:

```
webview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to disable scrolling for just one section of a UIWebView.

Comment: This will disable the scrolling globally for the entire view. I think the OP would like to disable scrolling for portions of his web view (and I do not know if it's possible, too).

Comment: Recomnet this solution. Keeps user interactions, disables scroll